# How to set precision value by passing value in \pgfmathprintnumber

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to create a Macro, that will set precision based on the user value set for the computation. 
My Macro is defined in preamble using \newenvironment

```
\newenvironment{calc}[1][1]{$\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=sci}
}
{ 
\pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=3]{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}$}
```

and call the macro through

```
\begin{calc}
\pgfmathparse{(1.45^2-1.40^2)/(1.55^2-1.45^2)}
\end{calc}
```

When I try to set the value by

```
\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=#1]{\pgfmathresult}
```

it doesn't work.

Comment: BTW, the problem is that arguments of `newenvironment` are not available in the *closing* commands. Package `environ` helps a lot for these cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcounter{Precision}
\newenvironment{calc}[1][1]{\setcounter{Precision}{#1}
$\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=sci}
}
{ 
\pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=\thePrecision]{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}$}
\begin{document}
\begin{calc}
\pgfmathparse{(1.45^2-1.40^2)/(1.55^2-1.45^2)}
\end{calc}
\begin{calc}[5]
\pgfmathparse{(1.45^2-1.40^2)/(1.55^2-1.45^2)}
\end{calc}
\end{document}
```